# Trailing Twelve Month Formula using MS Access Database

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, stored-procedures, select-query

I have a database named `Cash_Flow_Statements` and I need to create a saved query that calculates a Trailing Twelve Month (TTM) Free Cash Flow.

Here is an example of my database:

[image: Cash_Flow_Statement]

And here is the code for my saved query.  I have used this code for other calculations so I know it works.  I just don't know how to do a Trailing Twelve Month in SQL.

```
CREATE PROC " & Calculation & " AS _
SELECT Income_Statements.Ticker, Income_Statements.[Year], Income_Statements.Period, _
" & Formula & " AS TTM _
FROM (Income_Statements AS Income_Statements INNER JOIN Balance_Sheets AS Balance_Sheets ON (Income_Statements.Ticker = Balance_Sheets.Ticker) AND (Income_Statements.[Year] = Balance_Sheets.[Year]) AND (Income_Statements.Period = Balance_Sheets.Period)) _
INNER JOIN Cash_Flow_Statements AS Cash_Flow_Statements ON (Balance_Sheets.Ticker = Cash_Flow_Statements.Ticker) AND (Balance_Sheets.[Year] = Cash_Flow_Statements.[Year]) AND (Balance_Sheets.Period = Cash_Flow_Statements.Period)
```

I need the variable `Formula` to contain the equation that will calculate the Trailing Twelve Month for Free Cash Flow.  Here is what the math looks like:

Free Cash Flow TTM = Sum(Operating Cash Flow MRQ1 + Operating Cash Flow MRQ2 + Operating Cash Flow MRQ3 + Operating Cash Flow MRQ4) - Sum(Capital Expenditures MRQ1 + Capital Expenditures MRQ2 + Capital Expenditures MRQ3 + Capital Expenditures MRQ4)

MRQ = Most Recent Quarter

I need this formula to be in SQL.  How do I do this?

**UPDATE**

Per @Gord Thompson's answer below I have come up with this code:

```
SELECT Ticker, [Year], Period, (SELECT (SUM(su.Net_Cash_Flow_Operating) - SUM(su.Capital_Expenditures)) _
FROM (SELECT Ticker, [Year], Period, Net_Cash_Flow_Operating, Capital_Expenditures _
FROM Cash_Flow_Statements _
UNION ALL _
SELECT Ticker, [Year] + 1, Period - 4, Net_Cash_Flow_Operating, Capital_Expenditures _
FROM Cash_Flow_Statements) su _
WHERE su.Ticker = s.Ticker AND su.[Year] = s.[Year] AND (su.Period Between s.Period - 3 And s.Period)) _
AS SalesLast12Months _
FROM Cash_Flow_Statements AS s
```

When this is run by itself it returns exactly what I need.  But as I mentioned in my original post I need to be able to set the variable `Formula` to contain the SQL statement and then insert it into the existing SQL statement.

So I've tried to adapt @Gord Thompson answer and I've come up this this.

Formula:

```
Formula = “(SELECT (SUM(su.Net_Cash_Flow_Operating) - SUM(su.Capital_Expenditures)) _
FROM (SELECT Ticker, [Year], Period, Net_Cash_Flow_Operating, Capital_Expenditures _
FROM Cash_Flow_Statements UNION ALL SELECT Ticker, [Year] + 1, Period - 4, Net_Cash_Flow_Operating, Capital_Expenditures _
FROM Cash_Flow_Statements) su _
WHERE su.Ticker = Cash_Flow_Statements.Ticker AND su.[Year] = Cash_Flow_Statements.[Year] AND (su.Period Between Cash_Flow_Statements.Period - 3 And Cash_Flow_Statements.Period))”
```

SQL statement:

```
"CREATE PROC " & Calculation & " AS SELECT Income_Statements.Ticker, Income_Statements.[Year], Income_Statements.Period, " & Formula & " AS TTM _
FROM (Income_Statements AS Income_Statements _
INNER JOIN Balance_Sheets AS Balance_Sheets ON (Income_Statements.Ticker = Balance_Sheets.Ticker) AND (Income_Statements.[Year] = Balance_Sheets.[Year]) AND (Income_Statements.Period = Balance_Sheets.Period)) _
INNER JOIN Cash_Flow_Statements AS Cash_Flow_Statements ON (Balance_Sheets.Ticker = Cash_Flow_Statements.Ticker) AND (Balance_Sheets.[Year] = Cash_Flow_Statements.[Year]) AND (Balance_Sheets.Period = Cash_Flow_Statements.Period)
```

This is the result:

[image]

Again this is very close but not quite what I need.  I believe that I know what causes the code to not work when I adapt it but I don't know how to fix it yet.  In @Gord Thompson code the last line is `FROM Cash_Flow_Statements AS s`.  When I insert the variable formula into my existing SQL statement from my original post, the code is `FROM (Income_Statements AS Income_Statements _
    INNER JOIN Balance_Sheets AS Balance_Sheets ON (Income_Statements.Ticker = Balance_Sheets.Ticker) AND (Income_Statements.[Year] = Balance_Sheets.[Year]) AND (Income_Statements.Period = Balance_Sheets.Period)) _
    INNER JOIN Cash_Flow_Statements AS Cash_Flow_Statements ON (Balance_Sheets.Ticker = Cash_Flow_Statements.Ticker) AND (Balance_Sheets.[Year] = Cash_Flow_Statements.[Year]) AND (Balance_Sheets.Period = Cash_Flow_Statements.Period)`. **I'm almost positive that this is where the problems lies but do not know how to correct it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `Formula` should contain this:

```
SELECT (SUM(su.Net_Cash_Flow_Operating) - SUM(su.Capital_Expenditures)) FROM (SELECT Ticker, [Year], Period, Net_Cash_Flow_Operating, Capital_Expenditures FROM Cash_Flow_Statements UNION ALL SELECT Ticker, [Year] + 1, Period - 4, Net_Cash_Flow_Operating, Capital_Expenditures FROM Cash_Flow_Statements) su WHERE su.Ticker = c.Ticker AND su.[Year] = c.[Year] AND (su.Period Between c.Period - 3 And c.Period)
```

Comment: Glad to see that you got it sorted out.

Comment: @GordThompson Couldn't have done it without your help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's not get too hung up on the columns, let's concentrate on selecting the appropriate rows.

Say we had a table named [SalesSummary] containing

```
Item      FiscalYear  Quarter  TotalSales
--------  ----------  -------  ----------
bicycles        2011        1         100
bicycles        2011        2         200
bicycles        2011        3         300
bicycles        2011        4         400
bicycles        2012        1         500
bicycles        2012        2         600
bicycles        2012        3         700
bicycles        2012        4         800
ham             2011        1          10
ham             2011        2          20
ham             2011        3          30
ham             2011        4          40
ham             2012        1          50
ham             2012        2          60
ham             2012        3          70
ham             2012        4          80
```

If we wanted to create a query that showed the quarterly figures along with the total sales for the past 12 months (current quarter plus the previous 3 quarters) one might think that we would have to start messing around with `IIf()` to handle the "wrap around" from one FiscalYear to the next. Fortunately, we don't, because we can just replicate the same data with "fake" quarters for the next FiscalYear: 2011_Q(4) becomes 2012_Q(0), 2011_Q(3) becomes 2012_Q(-1), and so on.

```sql
    SELECT
        Item,
        FiscalYear,
        Quarter,
        TotalSales
    FROM SalesSummary
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Item,
        FiscalYear + 1,
        Quarter - 4,
        TotalSales
    FROM SalesSummary
```

returns

```
Item      FiscalYear  Quarter  TotalSales
--------  ----------  -------  ----------
bicycles        2011        1         100
bicycles        2011        2         200
bicycles        2011        3         300
bicycles        2011        4         400
bicycles        2012        1         500
bicycles        2012        2         600
bicycles        2012        3         700
bicycles        2012        4         800
ham             2011        1          10
ham             2011        2          20
ham             2011        3          30
ham             2011        4          40
ham             2012        1          50
ham             2012        2          60
ham             2012        3          70
ham             2012        4          80
bicycles        2012       -3         100
bicycles        2012       -2         200
bicycles        2012       -1         300
bicycles        2012        0         400
bicycles        2013       -3         500
bicycles        2013       -2         600
bicycles        2013       -1         700
bicycles        2013        0         800
ham             2012       -3          10
ham             2012       -2          20
ham             2012       -1          30
ham             2012        0          40
ham             2013       -3          50
ham             2013       -2          60
ham             2013       -1          70
ham             2013        0          80
```

If we save that query as [SalesUnion] then we can use it to produce our totals like so

```sql
SELECT 
    Item,
    FiscalYear,
    Quarter,
    TotalSales,
    (
        SELECT 
            SUM(su.TotalSales) 
            FROM SalesUnion su 
            WHERE su.Item = s.Item 
                AND su.FiscalYear = s.FiscalYear 
                AND (su.Quarter Between s.Quarter - 3 And s.Quarter)
    ) AS SalesLast12Months
FROM SalesSummary s
```

Or, if you don't want to rely on a saved query you can do it all in one go:

```sql
SELECT 
    Item,
    FiscalYear,
    Quarter,
    TotalSales,
    (
        SELECT 
            SUM(su.TotalSales) 
            FROM 
                (
                        SELECT
                            Item,
                            FiscalYear,
                            Quarter,
                            TotalSales
                        FROM SalesSummary
                    UNION ALL
                        SELECT
                            Item,
                            FiscalYear + 1,
                            Quarter - 4,
                            TotalSales
                        FROM SalesSummary
                ) su 
            WHERE su.Item = s.Item 
                AND su.FiscalYear = s.FiscalYear 
                AND (su.Quarter Between s.Quarter - 3 And s.Quarter)
    ) AS SalesLast12Months
FROM SalesSummary s
```

Either way, the results are

```
Item      FiscalYear  Quarter  TotalSales  SalesLast12Months
--------  ----------  -------  ----------  -----------------
bicycles        2011        1         100                100
bicycles        2011        2         200                300
bicycles        2011        3         300                600
bicycles        2011        4         400               1000
bicycles        2012        1         500               1400
bicycles        2012        2         600               1800
bicycles        2012        3         700               2200
bicycles        2012        4         800               2600
ham             2011        1          10                 10
ham             2011        2          20                 30
ham             2011        3          30                 60
ham             2011        4          40                100
ham             2012        1          50                140
ham             2012        2          60                180
ham             2012        3          70                220
ham             2012        4          80                260
```

Comment: This is great!  When I modify your answer to fit my program and run the code independently it works perfectly.  But when I try to use it within the code in my original post I run into some trouble.  What exactly would I put into the variable `Formula` in my original post?

Comment: I've update my original post to reflect changes I've made per your answer.